# Excel Charts: Is it possible to add specific text to the bars on a chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a chart which shows the daily purchases of each day in August 2015 against the daily purchases of each day in August 2015 in the bars, the lines show the total purchases in August 2014 for each day (i.e. on the 2nd day it'll add the amount of purchaess on the 1st and 2nd, on the 3rd it would be the amount on the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd etc) and the total amount of purchases in August 2015.

There are some low spikes on the Saturdays and Sundays.

So what I want to do is put the day name of the date on top of the bars, e.g. over the 2014 day 1 bar it would say Friday and over the 2015 day 1 bar it would say Saturday.

Is this possible?

Please note that I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text into cells in the worksheet, for example in an extra column or row adjacent to the chart source data.  Next, add data labels to the series.

Select the data labels with one click, then with a second single click select a single data label. Type a `=` sign into the formula bar and click the cell with the text you want to use as a label. If the cell is blank, the label will be blank.

Rinse and repeat for each data label.

[image]

If you find that too tedious, download the free [XY Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) add-in by Rob Bovey. It does exactly the same thing, only automated with VBA.

In Excel 2013 and higher, the data label formatting settings include a "value from cells" option natively, but they don't play well when opened with earlier Excel versions.

Comment: So are you saying to add a label, then within the label put `=` and then the cell that contains the date name?

Comment: Yes, like in the screenshot.